# Good practice for android multiplayer-board game

Tags: android, android-asynctask, multiplayer

I am writing a small game in android that basically is a turn-based boardgame, and I am having some questions about my multiplayer design, if it's good of bad practice.

The required speed of the client-server communication is slow at best, much like wordfeud, so I have used AsyncTask to do what I need, examples of tasks are: LoginTask, RegisterUserTask, StartGameTask, PlayMoveTask.

To initialize I can write:

```
VerifyUserTask verify = new VerifyUserTask();
verify.execute(username, password);
```

On the serverside I have a php script that takes the parameters sent in, and returns a result.

Back to the android again I might need to wait for a reply using

```
Boolean verified = verify.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The verifybit is rarely used, it's only when I need to verify that the user really is a valid user with a valid password.

I know this works, but is it an ok solution? Considering it's lightweight, fast enough, and I can log errors and responses.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid using `AsyncTask` for everything. It will bring you more problems than solutions.

Create an Android `Service` to handle all the backend logic and find a way to comunicate with your activities.

I would recommend you learning about `SyncAdapters`. Here is a [blog post](http://naked-code.blogspot.com/2011/05/revenge-of-syncadapter-synchronizing.html) with a nice introduction.